# Match brackets the kotlin way

Tags: parsing, kotlin

I'm giving Kotlin a go; coding contently, I have an ArrayList of chars which i want to classify depending on how brackets are matched:

```
(abcde)  // ok characters other than brackets can go anywhere
)abcde(  // ok matching the brackets 'invertedly' are ok
(({()})) // ok 
)()()([] // ok 
([)]     // bad can't have different overlapping bracket pairs
(((((    // bad all brackets need to have a match
```

My solution comes out(recursive):

```
//charList is a property
//Recursion starter'upper
private fun classifyListOfCharacters() : Boolean{
    var j = 0
    while (j < charList.size ) {
        if (charList[j].isBracket()){
            j = checkMatchingBrackets(j+1, charList[j])
        }
        j++
    }
    return j == commandList.size
}

private fun checkMatchingBrackets(i: Int, firstBracket :Char) : Int{
    var j = i
    while (j < charList.size ) {
        if (charList[j].isBracket()){
            if (charList[j].matchesBracket(firstBracket)){ 
                return j //Matched bracket normal/inverted
            }
            j = checkMatchingBrackets(j+1, charList[j])
        }
        j++
    }
    return j
}
```

This works, but is this how you do it in Kotlin? It feels like I've coded java in Kotlin syntax

Found this [Functional languages better at recursion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149167/are-functional-languages-better-at-recursion), I've tried thinking in terms of manipulating functions and sending them down the recursion but to no avail. I'd be glad to be pointed in the right direction, code, or some pseudo-code of a possible refactoring.

(Omitted some extension methods regarding brackets, I think it's clear what they do)

Comment: If your code does work it might be better suited for [CodeReview.se]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another, possibly a simpler approach to this problem is maintaining a stack of brackets while you iterate over the characters.

When you encounter another bracket:

- If it matches the top of the stack, you pop the top of the stack;
- If it does not match the top of the stack (or the stack is empty), you push it onto the stack.

If any brackets remain on the stack at the end, it means they are unmatched, and the answer is `false`. If the stack ends up empty, the answer is `true`.

This is correct, because a bracket at position `i` in a sequence can match another one at position `j`, only if there's no unmatched bracket of a different kind between them (at position `k`, `i < k < j`). The stack algorithm simulates exactly this logic of matching.

Basically, this algorithm could be implemented in a single `for`-loop:

```
val stack = Stack<Char>()

for (c in charList) {
    if (!c.isBracket())
        continue

    if (stack.isNotEmpty() && c.matchesBracket(stack.peek())) {
        stack.pop()
    } else {
        stack.push(c)
    }
}

return stack.isEmpty()
```

<sub>I've reused your extensions `c.isBracket(...)` and `c.matchesBracket(...)`. The [`Stack<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) is a JDK class.</sub>

This algorithm hides the recursion and the brackets nesting inside the abstraction of the brackets stack. Compare: your current approach implicitly uses the function call stack instead of the brackets stack, but the purpose is the same: it either finds a match for the top character or makes a deeper recursive call with another character on top.

Comment: As i Implemented this, the IDE proposes to replace the loop with stdlib operations. It filters{} on 'isBracket()' (this one simplifies imo, getting rid of the continue). It also uses a ForEach{} function, Does this have an advantage? Just looks less clear in this case to me

Answer (score 2):

Hotkey's answer (using a for loop) is great. However, you asked for an optimized recursion solution. Here is an optimized [tail recursive](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#tail-recursive-functions) function (Note the `tailrec` modifier before the function):

```
tailrec fun isBalanced(input: List<Char>, stack: Stack<Char>): Boolean = when {

    input.isEmpty() -> stack.isEmpty()

    else -> {

        val c = input.first()

        if (c.isBracket()) {
            if (stack.isNotEmpty() && c.matchesBracket(stack.peek())) {
                stack.pop()
            } else {
                stack.push(c)
            }
        }

        isBalanced(input.subList(1, input.size), stack)

    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("check: ${isBalanced("(abcde)".toList(), Stack())}")
}
```

This function calls itself until the input becomes empty and returns true if the stack is empty when the input becomes empty.

If we look at the decompiled Java equivalent of the generated bytecode, this recursion has been optimized to an efficient while loop by the compiler so we won't get `StackOverflowException` (removed Intrinsics null checks):

```
public static final boolean isBalanced(@NotNull String input, @NotNull Stack stack) {
      while(true) {
         CharSequence c = (CharSequence)input;
         if(c.length() == 0) {
            return stack.isEmpty();
         }

         char c1 = StringsKt.first((CharSequence)input);
         if(isBracket(c1)) {
            Collection var3 = (Collection)stack;
            if(!var3.isEmpty() && matchesBracket(c1, ((Character)stack.peek()).charValue())) {
               stack.pop();
            } else {
               stack.push(Character.valueOf(c1));
            }
         }

         input = StringsKt.drop(input, 1);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Note: the computational complexity of this recursive solution is increased by the `input.drop(1)` operation: it actually copies the input string except for one character each time (and the complexity of the agorithm becomes `O(n^2)`). I would suggest converting the string to a `List<Char>` first and then taking its `.subList(...)` view, which does not copy the items.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. `input.drop()` delegates to `String#subString` and it does create new String for every `subString` call. But I don't see any explicit iteration going on there to increase the time complexity.

Comment: It is unspecified whether `String#subString` copies the part of the underlying array, it is implementation-defined. In fact, since JDK 7 it [*does* create a new array](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/09/the-substring-method-in-jdk-6-and-jdk-7/), though in JDK 6 and earlier it didn't. There's no explicit iteration, but, because of copying the characters, taking substrings dropping one character each time takes `O(n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1) = O(n^2)` time.

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thank you.